# Pandas Dataframe Splitting YYYYMM Format into to columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataset that includes a column with a data stored in the YYYYMM format. After researching failed (I could not figure out how to apply datetime to this) I created a helper function to split it manually, and used the .apply() function to apply the function to every row. However this took a significant amount of time, and I can't help but believe there is a better way of doing this.

Any assisstance is appreciated.

```
def splitYearMonth (date:int):
    date = str(date)
    date = list(date)
    yearList = date[:4]
    year = ''
    year = year.join(yearList)
    year = int(year)
    monthList = date[-2:]
    month = ''
    month = month.join(monthList)
    month = int(month)
    return year, month
```

```
df[['Year', 'Month']] = df['YYYYMM'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(splitYearMonth(x)))
df.head()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
# convert to string if necessary:
df["YYYYMM"] = df["YYYYMM"].astype(str)

df["Year"], df["Month"] = df["YYYYMM"].str[:4], df["YYYYMM"].str[4:]

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   YYYYMM  Year Month
0  200101  2001    01
1  200102  2001    02
2  201012  2010    12
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions:

1. Use datetime.strpftime

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('20231202', '%Y%m%d')
datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 2, 0, 0)
```

2. Use dateutil.parser

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('20231202')
datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 2, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in surmising that using `apply()` with a custom function is not the fastest method. Vectorized operations (i.e. operations that are applied onto an entire data column at once) are in many cases orders of magnitude faster. To quote from the [following website](https://www.exxactcorp.com/blog/Deep-Learning/how-to-speed-up-python-pandas-by-over-300x):

> The reason why vectorization is so much faster than Looping/Iterating
> and Apply is that it doesn’t calculate the entire row every single
> time but instead applies the parameters to the entire dataset as a
> whole. Vectorization is a process where operations are applied to
> entire arrays of data at once, instead of operating on each element of
> the array individually. This allows for much more efficient use of
> memory and CPU resources.
>
> When using Loops or Apply to perform calculations on a Pandas data
> frame, the operation is applied sequentially. This causes repeated
> access to memory, calculations, and updated values which can be slow
> and resource-intensive.
>
> Vectorized operations, on the other hand, are implemented in Cython
> (Python in C or C++) and utilize the CPU's vector processing
> capabilities, which can perform multiple operations at once, further
> increasing performance by calculating multiple parameters at the same
> time. Vectorized operations also avoid the overhead of constantly
> accessing memory which is the crutch of Loop and Apply.

What does vectorized code look like in practice? It would for example be the following:

```
import pandas as pd

# Initialize example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"YYYYMM": [
    "202203",
    "202204",
    "202206",
    "202302",
    "202307",
]})

# Perform split
df["YYYYMM"] = df["YYYYMM"].astype(str)
df["year"] = df["YYYYMM"].str[:4]
df["month"] = df["YYYYMM"].str[4:]

print(df)
```

which prints:

```
   YYYYMM  year month
0  202203  2022    03
1  202204  2022    04
2  202206  2022    06
3  202302  2023    02
4  202307  2023    07
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work:

```
def splitYearMonth (date):
    date = pd.to_datetime(date, format='%Y%m')
    year = date.year
    month = date.month
    return year, month
```